# Collect ignoring negative exponential

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

I have the expression

```
1 + Exp[-2 x] (-1 - 2 x (1 + x))
```

I used `Expand` to get the x's to multiply within the parentheses, this gives

```
1 - Exp[-2 x] - 2 Exp[-2 x] x - 2 Exp[-2 x] x^2
```

I'm expected to get this into the form

```
1 - Exp[-2 x]*(1 + 2 x + 2 x^2)
```

I would expect

```
Collect[1 - Exp[-2 x] - 2 Exp[-2 x] x - 2 Exp[-2 x] x^2, -Exp[-2x]]
```

to do this but it only returns the expanded form again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Collect[..., -Exp[-2x]]` isn't working because some of the terms are `-2Exp[-2x]` and this doesn't match. If you use `Simplify[Collect[Expand[1+Exp[-2x](-1-2x(1+x))], Exp[-2x]]]`, you should get it in the format you're looking for.

Comment: i feel dumb, maybe a nap is in order before i continue to make such silly mistakes. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @KraftPunk I don't think it's a dumb mistake. To a human, it's obvious that we should be able to factor out `-Exp[-2x]`, but sometimes we have to find workarounds when it comes to computers.